# how to handle concurrency issues in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, socket.io, node-mongodb-native

I was preparing a chat application on nodejs using socket-io
The problem is with concurrent callbacks, explaination is as follows:
I keep in database socketId of related users, 
On disconnect event of socket-io I find the user based on its socket.id from mongodb, and do some db operations, remove the socket.id from subscriber socket list and update back the list(array in mongodb) in the same column.
Now the problem is when there are concurrent requests.

All the callbacks finds the socketId
Then all the callbacks create the list of socketids excluding itself(as event is disconnect) and then all updates back to db.

Problem in this approch is that Even though result is expected as blank column I end up with socketIds, only one is removed.

Hope was able to explain. Can anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong here?? This seems to be a very common problem what is the standard approach of solving same.??

code snippit:

```
if(sSocketIds.length > 1){
                    console.log("{disconnect} session contains multiple socket processing for removing the current one");
                    var nSubscriberSocketids =  [];
                    for(var cnt=0 ;sSocketIds.length>cnt ; cnt++){
                        if(sSocketIds[cnt]!=socket.id){
                            nSubscriberSocketids.push(sSocketIds[cnt]);
                        }
                    }
 // This below line is problem I always end up with n-1 socketIds due to concurrency.

                    __db.SessionFrame.update({"_id":session._id },{"subscriberSocketIds":nSubscriberSocketids}, function(err,count){
                        if(err){
                            console.error("{disonnect} error while removing socket: "+socket.id);
                        }else{

                            console.log("{disconnect} subscriber socket removed successfully: socketId: "+socket.id+" session will still persist");

                        }

                    });
                }
```

Comment: We can't answer questions about your specific code without seeing the code itself.  The problem you are having would be related to exactly how your code was structured so we need to see it.  A generic answer could be as much content as a whole programming class so an answer here at StackOverflow would need to be only about your specific code.  You probably have some variables overwriting each other with concurrent async operations.

Comment: Your assumption about concurrency is not correct.  The code you show above does not have a concurrency issue.  All it does is build an array with synchronous code and then make one async call.  That does not make a concurrency issue in node.js.  The issue is likely caused somewhere else or this isn't the entire relevant code.

Comment: @jfriend00 No this is what issue is ... the logs are printed proper ... when I close tabs one by one every thing works ...when I close the browser itself it gives multiple disconnect as per tab and this leads to concurrency issue. Let me know why u think otherwise.

Comment: I don't doubt you have a concurrency issue somewhere, but the code you've included in your question is not enough by itself to cause the issue.  If you are calling this code multiple times and some of these variables are shared among those operations, then that could cause a problem, but you aren't showing us that level of the code so we can't really see that kind of issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 let me try to explain :

Comment: 1) the whole of code written is in disconnect call back. 2) Now what happens is when we get multiple call together than then all the callbacks find that there are n elements in array. 3) They all create a array in which the socketId of the disconnect socket is not included. 4) Then they do one by one and calls the update  function 5) the last call ends up with updating the n-1 sockets. 5) If the call were synchronus or the request were sequential with good amount of delay then the end result would have been a empty array. Now did  you got the issue ??

Comment: Why can't you show the whole disconnect callback code?  Then, we could suggest how to fix it.